# Optimal design for multinomial logit model

Tags: experiment-design, ordered-logit, multinomial-logit

I would like to obtain an experimental design for a multinomial logit model. I have 4 factors of 4 levels. I will need 40 separate experiments. This means I cannot run an orthogonal design. I could obtain a d-optimal design, optimised for a linear regression.

However, could I also obtain a d-optimal design, optimised for a multinomial or ordered logit model? Is this programmed in any common software?

Answer (score 1):

You could use NGENE software to obtain d-optimal (or d-efficient) design for MNL model (random parameters logit model as well). So far I remember, Street & Burgess have also developed a "tool" on their website to generate D-optimal design for MNL model (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1755534513700162#). Strictly speaking D-optimality or D-Efficiency requires an information about the effects you plan to estimate. In the particular case of null/no information, orthogonal design and d-optimal designs would perform almost equally well. I would not de facto rule out OD from your list.

Comment: There may be some R packages that you can use, see  https://CRAN.R-project.org/view=ExperimentalDesign